# Auto load contents at the end of the page using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter. I have created a page that has lot of contents on single page. I want to load those contents in a fancy way like it should load some contents and as we scroll down and reach at the end of the page then it should display some sort of loading feature and load other contents and so on..

The example of such websites can be seen in social networking sites such as Facebook, Twitter or Quora.

I have thoroughly searched for it and unable to find anything suitable.

Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a "Infinite scroll" plugin. If you google that you can find some plugins like [infinite-scroll](https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll) and [jScroll](http://jscroll.com/)

The basic functionality of these plugins is to "monitor" the users position and, at the end of just before the page content ends, the plugin makes an `$.ajax` request to get more results and add those results to the dom.